# Redirect write directory

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, icloud

Service downloads to C but want D. Cannot change its settings.

Can I "redirect" the download on OS-side? The original write shouldn't happen - i.e. "detect -> move" won't do.

**Context**: iCloud syncs to `C:\Users\<name>\iCloudDrive`

Comment: Where are you downloading these "Applications" from? If its from a web browser you can just change the download directory. Please edit your question and provide more details on what you're trying to achieve. It will help others give you a more accurate answer.

Comment: @mully iCloud is the service, which syncs to a local directory (like OneDrive) which cannot be changed.

Comment: Try this: https://www.guidingtech.com/change-icloud-drive-folder-location-windows-10/  I am pretty sure that you can change the iCloud directory

Comment: @mully Trying all steps on that and related articles at best create copies of downloaded files in D.

Comment: Maybe look into creating a shim Google for CorrectFilePaths shim